# Show that the function $f(z) = \log (z-i)$ is analytic everywhere except the portion on $x \le 0$ on the line $y =1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Note: We are meant to consider principle branch only

The log can be written as
$$\ln(|z-i|) + i (\theta)$$
where $\theta$ is the argument of $z - i$

$$ = \ln (\sqrt {x^2 + (y-1)^2}) + i (\theta)$$

Since $y =1$

$$ = \ln (|x|) + i (\theta)$$

But if we check if the $u(x,y)$ is harmonic, it appears that

For $x>0$
$$u_{xx} + u_{yy} = 0$$
$$ \implies \frac{1}{x^2} = 0$$
which is only possible when $x \to \infty$

and for $x < 0$ we have a similar situation.

So it should be that the function is not analytic anywhere on the line $y =1$, but that is contradictory to the required statement. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the Laplacian at a point $(x,y)$ with $y=1$ you cannot put $y=1$ in the beginning and start differentiating. You have to first find $u_{xx}+u_{yy}$ at a general point an then plug in $y=1$.

[Suppose $f(x)=x$. To find $f'(1)$ you cannot say $f(1)=1$ and the derivative of $1$ is $0$, so $f'(1)=0$. Differentiate and then put $x=1$, not the other way around.].

You should get $u_{xx}=\frac {(y-1)^{2}-x^{2}}{(x^{2}+(y-1)^{2})^{2}}$ and $u_{yy}=\frac {x^{2}-(y-1)^{2}}{(x^{2}+(y-1)^{2})^{2}}$

For analyticity writing $f$ as a composition of natural logarithm (which is analytic except on the nergative real axis) and the function $z\to z-i$ makes it clear that $f$ is analytic in the stated region.

Comment: Ok but the result ends up being the same, $u_{xx} + u_{yy}$ is never becoming zero since it is $\frac{x+y-1}{\sqrt {x^2 + (y-1)^2}}$

Comment: You need to check your calulations. The result is correct and $f$ is analytic in the complement of $\{x+iy: x \leq 0, y=1\}$. @Aditya

Comment: Ok here $u = \ln \sqrt {x^2 + (y-1)^2}$ right? And upon calculating $u_{xx} + u_{yy} = \frac {x+y-1}{\sqrt {x^2 + (y-1)^2}}$? Upon substituting $y=1$ we get $\frac{1}{|x|}$. Is this correct?

Comment: See my answer now. For  a start write $u=\frac  1 2 \ln (x^{2}+(y-1)^{2})$. That simplifies differentiation  a lot.

Comment: Sorry I understood, very silly mistake on my part . Thanks

Comment: Is there a shorter way to do this? Because calculating the double derivative is a lot of work

Comment: Also since $u_{xx} + u_{yy} =0 $ for all $x$, do we need to make a similar calculating for $v$ as well to finally verify?

Comment: For analyticicity it is not enough to verify that $u$ and $v$ are separately harmonic functions. Instead, you have to very C-R equations. But writing $f$ as a composition of natural logarithm (which is analytic except on the nergative real axis) and the function $z\to z-i$ makes it clear that $f$ is analytic in the stated region @Aditya

Comment: I don’t get it. You mean we write it as a composition $f(g(z))$ where $f(z) = \log z$ and $g(z) = z - i$ Now $f$ is analytic as long as $Re(z)\ge 0$ or $Re(g(z))\ge 0$. Is this correct? But then this is effective regardless of the value of $y$

Comment: $log (z-i)$ is analytic at $z$ if $z-i$ is not a non-negative real number which means $z$ is not of the form $i+t$ with $t \leq 0$. @Aditya

Comment: So $z-i$ cannot be a negative real, but it can be complex right?

Comment: Ok I understand now, thank you so much, but just to confirm, log functions can have a complex argument and still be analytic right?